# IntelliJ - New designer feature - how to teach him to know selectors as button backgrounds

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Perhaps anyone has a tip:

First of all, there is a great new feature in IntelliJ 11 - supporting android design view in XML files. But its not perfect (well, its free and pretty useful already, so I am not complaining).

Its missing support for selectors. So if you reference a drawable selector, instead of the background, it stays blank in the designer.

One workaround is referencing the _passive image instead of the selector during debug, and then switching it back. But this is a lot of search and replace in layout files, and also error prone (forgetting to set it back, buttons will not change color).

Any idea of a workaround for this? Or anyone know if this is fixed in an EAP version of IntelliJ.

Chris

Here is the "selector code", but I think anyone reading this questions should know what I am talking about (using selectors instead of direct drawables as e.g. background)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/quiz_question_bg_single_active"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/quiz_question_bg_single_passive"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
          android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/quiz_question_bg_single_disabled"/>
</selector>
```

(Kind of crosspost here http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/432416)

Comment: Have you tried both? In my opinion (new to both) the code features (cleanup, formatting, refactoring) in IntelliJ is way ahead of eclipse. But that may be a matter of personal taste. After 500h+ of Android development I even try IntelliJ shortcuts in VS2010 :-) Thank god for Resharper there!

Comment: No, I've never tried both. Google says Eclipse is the IDE for Android. SO I've tried that. I also find it pretty easy to edit XML by hand. I'm sure IntelliJ is very good but as I'm constantly running out of time with current projects (bad programmer as I am) I  have never had a chance to try it

Comment: Yeah, same here. And btw, I also edit by hand, the designer does not have drag and drop (useless most of the time anyway) - but seeing the result instantly is nice. And give IntelliJ a try, especially if you arent locked in eclipse (e.g. by using it for 5 years) - for me it saved tons of time in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a post in IntelliJ forum, this seems to be a tool bug by google.
I created an issue, so if you want to know about the current state of affairs, see here

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22926